# Performing a pandas grouby on a list containing 2 and 3 character string subset of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Say I have a simple dataframe with the names of people. I perform a `groupby` on `name`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'name': ['George', 'John', 'Tim', 'Joe', 'Issac', 'George', 'Tim'] })

df1 = df.groupby('name')
```

**Question:** How can I select out a table of specific names out of a list which contains a string subset of the names, either 2 or 3 characters?

e.g say I have the following list where both `Tim & Geo` are the first 3 characters of some entries in the `name` column and `Jo` is the first 2 characters of a certain entry in the `name` column.

```
list = ['Jo', 'Tim', 'Geo']
```

**Attempted:** My initial thought was to create new columns in the original dataframe which were either a 2 or 3 character subset of the `name` column and then try grouping by that however since 2 and 3 string characters are different the grouping wouldn't output the correct result.

Not sure whether it would be better to use some if condition such as `if v in list is len(2) groupby(2char) else groupby(3char)` and output the result as 1 dataframe.

```
list
df1['name_2char_subset] = df1['name'].str[0:2]
df1['name_3char_subset] = df1['name'].str[0:3]

if v in list is len(2):
df2 = df1.groupby('name_2char_subset')
else:
df2 = df1.groupby('name_3char_subset')
```

**Desired Output:** Since there are 2 counts of each of Jo, Geo & Tim. The output should group by each case. ie for `Jo` there are both `John & Joe` hence a count of 2 in the groupby.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Jo', 'Tim', 'Geo'], 'col1': [2,2,2]})
```

How could we group by name and output the entries in `name` which have the given initial characters as in the list?
Any alternative ways of doing this will be helpful. For example, can perform this in the group by of extract values in the list after the group by has been performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First dont use `list` for variable, because python code word. Then use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for test if match by starting of strings by `^` and count in [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
L = ['Jo', 'Tim', 'Geo']

pat = '|'.join(r"^{}".format(x) for x in L)
df = (df['name'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
                .dropna()
                .value_counts()
                .reindex(L, fill_value=0)
                .rename_axis('name')
                .reset_index(name='col1'))

print (df)
  name  col1
0   Jo     2
1  Tim     2
2  Geo     2
```

Your solution:

```
L = ['Jo', 'Tim', 'Geo']

s1 = df['name'].str[:2]
s2 = df['name'].str[:3]

df = (s1.where(s1.isin(L)).fillna(s2.where(s2.isin(L)))
                .dropna()
                .value_counts()
                .reindex(L, fill_value=0)
                .rename_axis('name')
                .reset_index(name='col1'))
print (df)
  name  col1
0   Jo     2
1  Tim     2
2  Geo     2
```

Solution from deleted answer with change by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for test if starting string by list:

```
L = ['Jo', 'Tim', 'Geo']
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name': L})
df3['col1'] = df3['name'].apply(lambda x: sum(df['name'].str.startswith(x)))
print (df3)
  name  col1
0   Jo     2
1  Tim     2
2  Geo     2
```

EDIT: If need groupby more columns use first or second solution, assign columns back and aggregate by names aggregation in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'name': ['George', 'John', 'Tim', 'Joe', 'Issac', 'George', 'Tim'] })

print (df)

L = ['Jo', 'Tim', 'Geo']

pat = '|'.join(r"^{}".format(x) for x in L)
df['name'] = df['name'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
    
df = df.groupby('name').agg(sum_age=('age','sum'), col1=('name', 'count'))
print (df)
      sum_age  col1
name               
Geo         7     2
Jo          6     2
Tim        10     2
```

Comment: Great thanks. I might add something that I missed to my question but what happens if say I have more columns in `df` like `age` and I wanted that to be included along with the count in the groupby output using the list.

(taking your deleted solution) Would I add another column like `df3['age_total'] = df3['name'].apply(lambda x: sum(df['age']))`?